# Glob and group file names in PHP

Tags: php, mp3, glob

Suppose there is a folder in the server called "mp3" with plenty of mp3 files, "a1.mp3", "a2.mp3", "a3.mp3", "a4.mp3", "ao0.mp3", "ao2.mp3", "ao3.mp3", "ci1.mp3", "ci2.mp3" etc.

```
    foreach (glob('sound/*.mp3') as $filename) {
        if (!in_array($filename,$exclude_files)) {
            $outputtext .= "<p>".preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', basename($filename))."</p>";
        }
    }echo $outputtext;
```

My source code is as above and the current result is:

a1
a2
a3
ao0
ao2
ao3
ci1
ci2

But the result what I want is to group all same patterns as follows:

a - 123
ao - 023
ci - 12

Thanks for all your reply.

Comment: 1. it is totally unclear what logic should lead from the file names to your suggested output and 2. why don't you take a look at the documentation of the `glob()` function and give it a try yourself? Then, if you run into an issue you really cannot solve yourself, _then_ is the time to ask a question here and post your code along with a detailed description of what does not work as expected. Thanks.

Comment: In fact I have tried the source code to read all the mp3 files and it works. But I can't do the effect that I asked here. I will post the source code here soon.

Comment: Great! When adding your code to your question then please also explain the logic you want to implement since it does not become clear from the sparse information you currently give in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach (glob($path.'*.mp3') as $filename) {
        if (!in_array($filename,$exclude_files)) {
            if (preg_match('/[0-9]/', $filename, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                // Starting after "sound/", so the starting position is 6
                $filenamestr[$n] = substr($filename, 6, $matches[0][1]-6+1);
                $n++;
            }
        }
    }

    $totalfiles = $n--;
    $mp3 = "";
    $o = 0;
    $p = 0;
    for ($l = 0; $l < $totalfiles; $l++) {
        if (substr($filenamestr[$l], 0, strlen($filenamestr[$l])-1) == substr($filenamestr[$l-1], 0, strlen($filenamestr[$l-1])-1)) {
            // Connect file names to an array when current file name is the same as previous one
            $p++;
            $mp3file[$o][$p] = substr($filenamestr[$l], -1);
            $mergemp3file[$o] .= $mp3file[$o][$p];
        } else {
            // Produce another array for file name when current file name is different from previous one
            $o++;
            $p = 0;
            $mp3file[$o][$p] = substr($filenamestr[$l], 0, strlen($filenamestr[$l])-1)." - ".substr($filenamestr[$l], -1);
            // Collect sound files for each file name
            $mergemp3file[$o] .= $mp3file[$o][$p];
        }
    }

    // Generate merged sound files for each file name
    $totalmp3 = $o--;
    for ($o = 1; $o < $totalmp3; $o++) {
        $outputtext .= "<br/>".$mergemp3file[$o].chr(13);
    }
```